# Tableau server 9.1 dynamic logo

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I'm running a private Tableau Server on 9.1.

I've set up a DNS and made my tableau reachable with 2 URL (toto.com and tata.com).

I have 2 logos, each one associated to one URL (logo A and logo B).

I would like Tableau Server to display :
- Logo A when reached with toto.com
- Logo B when reached with tata.com

To me, the only way to do this is to hack through html/javascript source code, as presented in this link : http://tableaulove.tumblr.com/post/114891230420/can-i-still-hack-the-login-screen-in-tableau , modifying the code in this path C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\9.0\vizportalclient\public\

But it just won't work.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this answer right here : http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2015/05/26/fix-tableau-server-v9-logos/